# Автоматическая прокрутка при добавлении строк в qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку таблицы вниз при добавлении новых строк в qtablewidget?
Испульзую QT5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTableWidget::scrollToBottom` или как более гибкий вариант `QTableWidget::scrollToItem`